# Convert time series into dataframe so that each row has consequtive time slices

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a time series as pandas Series object. I want to find out if I can predict the value of  a day by looking at the values from past 60 days. For that reason, I want to convert my time series to a data frame that look like this (so that I can feed this to a learning algorithm);

```
Day 1    Day2     ... Day 60   value
986.55   990.95   ... 1618.86  1655.5
990.95   1017.85  ... 1655.5   1669.8
1017.85  1053.68  ... 1669.8   1707.2
```

How can I do such conversion?

My time series look like this (index is a pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex);

```
DATE
1991-01-02 986.55
1991-01-03 990.95
1991-01-04 1017.85
1991-01-05 1053.68
```

Comment: and what does your timeseries look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Says `s` is the series you get. You can create a DataFrame from it by slicing the series day after day:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([s[i:i+60].values for i in range(len(s)-60)])
```

Then you rename the columns:

```
df.columns=['Day '+str(i) for i in range(1,61)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doffset = pd.tseries.offsets.Day(60)

f = lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist()).T

pd.concat([f(df['value'].ix[i:i+doffset]) for i in df.index])
```